# Cannot create Apple ID either from iOS of website - An unknown error has occurred

Tags: apple-id, ios

I'm trying to create an Apple ID from a used iPhone 5 that I have purchased but it's failing.

After failing on the iPhone I tried to create one from the website but I'm always getting an "An unknown error has occurred"

No clue on how to solve it.

[image]

Comment: First of all, you should _never_ show a verification code publicly. Did it happened only recently (today) or have you tried it since some time?

Comment: OK. Well the verification code changed all the times I tried to create so I didn't think it was a problem. I have tried for the past hour and a half and it's always failing.

Comment: Ok, about the verification code, it's just that Apple says so (for security apparently). And I asked that because it might have been a system down on Apple side, but it [doesn't seems](https://www.apple.com/support/systemstatus/) to be any issue there...

Comment: Could the phone be stolen?

Comment: I don't think that could lead to this issue, because you can create an Apple ID from any device (but I'm not 100% sure)

Comment: Have you tried clearing your Mac's Safari cache?  In Safari go to `Preferences -> Privacy -> Manage Website Data` and search for `apple`.  Highlight anything showing and hit `Remove`.  Restart Safari and try again.  Does that help?

Comment: I think it was an Apple server problem even though the status page was showing the server as active. Managed to create the ID the next day.

Comment: I have exactly the same error. Tried it in Safari and Chrome on the Mac and again with Safari on my iPhone with the same result. I hope tomorrow it will just work like @FabrizioMazzoni mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a different network to access the website. Sometimes changing networks can cause that issue. If you arent at liberty to change networks then restarting your device can help.